# Dynamic layout content and rails request methods

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, layout

So my basic problem is this, I want to have a footer in my app/views/layout that changes depending on what request method is being used. Specifically I want to have something in the footer that says "edit" on a *show* request and links to an *edit* request. What I'm looking to do is to have something to the effect of:

```
<%=if method == 'edit' %>
<%= render :partial=> edit_button :object => some how get the current instance variable %>
```

..in my footer and in the edit_button.html.erb would be:

```
<%=link to 'edit', edit_<resource>_path(resource)%>
```

I know this is this is a little vague, but I think it's because I'm not thinking about the problem correctly. I realize I could just have three different layouts, one for "edit", "show", and "new", but that seems like overkill and is definitely not DRY. Could someone point me in the right direction here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way of doing this is to use `yield` and `content_for` directives. For example

**In layout**

You can do:

```
<%= yield :footer_links %>
```

**In Show page**

You can do:

```
<% content_for :footer_links do %>
  <%= link to 'edit', edit_<resource>_path(resource) %>
<% end %>
```

And so on. You can pass any content to the `yield` block via `content_for`.

Comment: Thank you, this is exactly what I was looking for, and although I had known of yield/content_for I had not thought to use it in this context.